# Jquery: Change Menu Item Address when not located on Homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a homepage that has its main menu.
One of the Menu items called "Contacts" uses Jquery to activate the Smooth Scroll to the  "Our Contacts" block located below on that same Homepage.

- "Contacts" menu item has its a `href="#contact-js"` that links it to "Our Contacts" block.
- " Our Contacts" block has its assigned `id="contact-js"`

That smooth scroll work perfectly well!!
**My problem is** that when I leave the **Home Page** and open another page or post on my website I see the same menu displayed in the header section of my website.
When I press that "Contacts" menu item nothing happens because it is used to run that smooth scroll action on the **Home Page**.

**My Question is** how to assign this "Contact" menu item (it has a `class="menu-item-28"`) a different URL pointing to my Contact Page when the visitor is located on a page or on a post (not on the home page)?

That's what I was struggling to compile:

```
$("#menu-item-27 a").on("click", function(event) {
    if(location.href != "http://www.mynewmedia.dev") { 
  window.location.href = "http://www.mynewmedia.dev/Contacts-Page/";
    }

});
```

Thanks is advance!!!

Best Regards,
Alexander

Comment: Is this WordPress? I assume so with the `menu-item-28` class.

Comment: What is the page ID on the homepage `<body>` tag. It would be something like `page-id-XX`, if this is indeed WordPress.

Comment: Hello Andy! Yes this is wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this if you really want to take them to a full contact page instead of have them go back to the homepage contact section. If you want to take them back to the homepage section follow the advice from "I wrestled a bear once".

```
<script type="test/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        if (!jQuery('body').hasClass('page-id-XX')) {
            jQuery('.menu-item-28 a').attr('href', 'http://www.mynewmedia.dev/Contacts-Page/');
        }
    });
</script>
```

You'd need to update page-id-XX to use the actual homepage body class that your homepage has if this is indeed WordPress. I hate to speculate, but I believe it is based on your menu item class.

If its not WordPress, this will still work if you add a class to the `<body>` tag that is only present on the homepage, and then add that class name to `if (!jQuery('body').hasClass('classNameHere')) {`.

Comment: Hello Andy! Thank you so much for looking into this. I have installed your script. It's Almost working:) Still trying to figure it out. Now the Smooth Scroll works fine on the home page. Now when I open another page on my website and Hover over that Button I do see the new address appear! The problem is that when I click the button - it doesn't work.....

Comment: Sorry it turn out I use  "event.preventDefault();" for that button. Once I removed the line - everything works perfectly Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! Please accept this answer if you are satisfied!

Answer (score 0):

You just need tom change it to the full url of whatever page has the contact info and then add the `#contact-js` behind it.

```
<a href='http://www.pageWithContactInfo.com/#contact-js'>contact us</a>
```

Have a look at this w3c link:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri

Note the "#fragment-uri" which will scroll to the element on that page with `id='fragment-uri'`.

Click on that link for more info.